# Hiding a form with javascript - Not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide two fields on my form depending on the selection of the use on the radio field. This is the field HTML:

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementByClass('extra').style.display = 'none';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementByClass('extra').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="form-radio">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="show1();" /><i class="helper"></i>
      I can come
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="show2();" /><i class="helper"></i>
      I cant come
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group extra">
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">Dietary Requirements</label>
  <i class="bar"></i>
</div>

<div class="form-group extra">
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">What song would you like played?</label>
  <i class="bar"></i>
</div>
```

It should work by hiding the dietary requirements and what song fields when the user selects "I can't come" on the radio field. I get the following result:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: show2 is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):627)
```

Comment: The problem is two div having same class name 'extra' javascript doesn't know which one to hide and which one to show. If you can rename one of the classes and try it.

Comment: While you do have problems with your code, it does not have the problem you are asking about. You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: Did you, for example, just forget the `<script>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails for two reasons:

1. There is no method of `document` called `getElementByClass`. The correct method to use is `getElementsByClassName`.
2. The method`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` and not a single element, so setting `style.display` for the `HTMLCollection` won't have the desired effect, because you are not setting it for each individual element of it, but rather for the `HTMLCollection` object itself.

**The correct code is:**

```
function show() {
  /* Cache the collection. */
  var extra = document.getElementsByClassName('extra');

  /* Iterate over every element in the collection. */
  [].forEach.call(extra, function (element) {
     element.style.display = 'block';
  });
}

function hide() {
  /* Cache the collection. */
  var extra = document.getElementsByClassName('extra');

  /* Iterate over every element in the collection. */
  [].forEach.call(extra, function (element) {
     element.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function show() {
  /* Cache the collection. */
  var extra = document.getElementsByClassName('extra');

  /* Iterate over every element in the collection. */
  [].forEach.call(extra, function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
  });
}

function hide() {
  /* Cache the collection. */
  var extra = document.getElementsByClassName('extra');

  /* Iterate over every element in the collection. */
  [].forEach.call(extra, function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div class="form-radio">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="show();" checked/>
      <i class="helper"></i>
      I can come
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="hide();"/>
      <i class="helper"></i>
      I cant come
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group extra">
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">Dietary Requirements</label>
  <i class="bar"></i>
</div>

<div class="form-group extra">
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">What song would you like played?</label>
  <i class="bar"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery instead of javascript.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('input:radio[name="radio"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'hide'){
          $('.extra').hide();    
         }
           else {
          $('.extra').show();   
         }
        });

         });




      <div class="form-radio">
       <div class="radio">
        <label>
           <input type="radio" name="radio" value="show" /><i class="helper"></i>
          I can come
         </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
       <label>
           <input type="radio" name="radio" value="hide" /><i class="helper"></i>
           I cant come
         </label>
           </div>
         </div>

          <div class="form-group extra">
          <input type="text" required="required" />
          <label class="control-label" for="input">Dietary Requirements</label>
          <i class="bar"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group extra">
          <input type="text" required="required" />
           <label class="control-label" for="input">What song would you like played?</label>
           <i class="bar"></i>
             </div>
```